# How to decode storage value of a struct

Tags: solidity, evm, storage

On Uniswap V3 Pool contract, we have slot0 struct which is located on slot 0 of the storage

```
    struct Slot0 {
        // the current price
        uint160 sqrtPriceX96;
        // the current tick
        int24 tick;
        // the most-recently updated index of the observations array
        uint16 observationIndex;
        // the current maximum number of observations that are being stored
        uint16 observationCardinality;
        // the next maximum number of observations to store, triggered in observations.write
        uint16 observationCardinalityNext;
        // the current protocol fee as a percentage of the swap fee taken on withdrawal
        // represented as an integer denominator (1/x)%
        uint8 feeProtocol;
        // whether the pool is locked
        bool unlocked;
    }
    /// @inheritdoc IUniswapV3PoolState
    Slot0 public override slot0;
```

I use `web3.eth.getStorageAt(contractAddress, 0)` to get the storage data, example are like this example `0x0001001c201c200eb8ff799900000000000000002dd4311936cf0097586f377c`

the question is, how to decode that hex value ? tried to decode it to number which is not mean anything ..

I have read few article like this https://medium.com/@dariusdev/how-to-read-ethereum-contract-storage-44252c8af925 , but I'm stuck with finding the key of the storage, which is I don't know if that key is the correct answer for my problem ..

This is the contract that I use as my example https://arbiscan.io/address/0xb52781c275431bd48d290a4318e338fe0df89eb9#code

Also, I know about calling slot0 function on the contract to get the value. But All I want is able to decode the value on the storage ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a struct is just the logical grouping, from the storage perspective the structs can be omitted. So just the variables/property types define how the storage is packed.

A slot occupies **32Bytes**

```typescript
uint160 sqrtPriceX96;              // 160/8 = 20B
int24 tick;                        // 24/8 = 3B
uint16 observationIndex;           // 2B
uint16 observationCardinality;     // 2B
uint16 observationCardinalityNext; // 2B
uint8 feeProtocol;                 // 1B
bool unlocked;                     // 1B
```

Altogether it requires **31 Bytes**, so indeed can be packed into a single slot.
The values are packed(aligned) from **right** to **left**. In hex format, a byte has **2 chars**.

- `sqrtPriceX96`:
- 0x0001001c201c200eb8ff7999**00000000000000002dd4311936cf0097586f377c**
- `sqrtPriceX96`:
- 0x0001001c201c200eb8**ff7999**00000000000000002dd4311936cf0097586f377c
- `observationIndex`:
- 0x0001001c201c20**0eb8**ff799900000000000000002dd4311936cf0097586f377c
- `observationCardinality`:
- 0x0001001c20**1c20**0eb8ff799900000000000000002dd4311936cf0097586f377c
- `observationCardinalityNext`:
- 0x000100**1c20**1c200eb8ff799900000000000000002dd4311936cf0097586f377c
- `feeProtocol`:
- 0x0001**00**1c201c200eb8ff799900000000000000002dd4311936cf0097586f377c
- `unlocked`:
- 0x00**01**001c201c200eb8ff799900000000000000002dd4311936cf0097586f377c
- `unused storage`:
- 0x**00**01001c201c200eb8ff799900000000000000002dd4311936cf0097586f377c

Comment: I was wrong then, I also tried to unpack the value from left to right. I read somewhere about get the storage layout from remix by compile the contract and get the offset of the slot storage. I thought the offset was left to right ..